# Dificuldade em filtrar informações

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq

Sei que meu problema é lógica e isso deve partir de mim, eu sei, mas às vezes uma luz, não um código pronto, mas o apontar de um caminho nos ajuda bastante.

1) Tenho 6 ComboBox em minha View que fazem os filtros para uma pesquisa.

2) Essa pesquisa, deverá montar uns CheckBox's, baseado no filtro passado. Acontece que essa montagem dos checkbox's, a LINQ que trás o resultado é a minha model. Alguns me disseram aqui que passar parâmetro direto para a Model, quebra o paradigma da OO e concordo. Nesse momento começa meu problema.

3) Estou tendo dificuldade para fazer isso. Preencho os parâmetros na View e via JQuery eu os pego. Agora como eu faço para distribuir para a minha model, de forma que a LINQ seja executada com esses filtros sendo passados no where da LINQ ou Lambda. Abaixo minha Model.

```
public static List<MontaArvoreAcao> montaArvoreAcao( )
        {
            RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();

            var monta_arvore = (from rup in db.Ruptura
                                join ap in db.Apresentacao on rup.Codigo_Apresentacao equals (ap.Codigo_Apresentacao)
                                join mo in db.Motivo on rup.IDMotivo equals (mo.IDMotivo)
                                join pdv in db.PDV on rup.CodigoPDV equals (pdv.CodigoPDV)

                                where rup.IDMotivo != 6

                                //group rup by new { rup.IDRuptura} into gr

                                select new MontaArvoreAcao
                                {
                                    IDRuptura = rup.IDRuptura,
                                    DataRuptura = rup.DataRuptura,
                                    IDMotivo = rup.IDMotivo,
                                    Motivo = rup.Motivo.Motivo1,
                                    IDOrigem = rup.IDOrigem,
                                    CodigoPDV = rup.CodigoPDV,
                                    UF = rup.PDV.UF,
                                    Cidade = pdv.Cidade,
                                    CnpjDescricao = pdv.Cnpj + " - " + pdv.Descricao,
                                    Codigo_Apresentacao = rup.Codigo_Apresentacao,
                                    Unidade_Negocio = ap.Unidade_Negocio,
                                    Codigo_Unidade_Negocio = ap.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio,
                                    Franquia = ap.Franquia,
                                    Familia = ap.Familia,
                                    Descricao = ap.Descricao,
                                    Tipo_Rede = pdv.Tipo_PDV,
                                    Farmacia = pdv.Descricao
                                }).ToList().OrderBy(r => r.IDMotivo);

            return monta_arvore.ToList();
        }
```

Os parâmetros vindo da View são:

```
Estado, Cidade, Tipo_PDV, Descricao, UN, Familia de Produto.
```

Alterei a minha Action para receber parâmetros, conforme vocês estão vendo. Como eu passo os parâmtros para esses argumentos?

```
public ActionResult Acao(string _uf, string _cidade, string _descricao)
        {
            string user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1].Trim();

            ViewBag.User = user;

            ViewData["ListaUn"] = MontaArvoreAcao.CriarListaArvoreUn(_uf,_cidade,_descricao);

            ViewData["ListaFamilia"] = MontaArvoreAcao.CriarListaArvoreFamilia();

            ViewData["ListaProd"] = MontaArvoreAcao.CriarListaArvoreProduto();

            ViewData["ListaPdv"] = MontaArvoreAcao.CriarListaArvorePdv();

            return View(MontaArvoreAcao.montaArvoreAcao());
        }
```

Comment: Vou te dar uma dica. Procure achar um título curtinho que explique muito bem qual é o problema. Muitas vezes isto só vai ajudar as pessoas se interessarem por sua pergunta. Mas algumas vezes vai até facilitar você entender melhor o problema. Sim, vai dar trabalho pensar nesse título tão bom. E aí que tá o segredo, faz você forçar o cérebro com mais profundidade no problema. Claro que o ideal é fazer com texto. Não estou dizendo que o texto geral está ruim mas que se você realmente mergulhar de cabeça pode lhe ajudar diretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Lembrei-me que via jquery eu faço isso. Já está resolvido.

function.....

```
$.ajax({

    url: '/Controller/Action',

    ......

    data: JSON.stringify({ _uf: $('#cbxUf').val(), _cidade: $('#cbxCidade :selected').text(), _descricao:   $('#cbxDescricao :selected').text() }),

E assim por diante

})
```